# MongoDB add database and user after auth

Tags: mongodb

I've an instance of MongoDB 4 running on server with replica set on same machine with differente ports.

I've created a super user using these commands:

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "mongo_admin",pwd: "password",roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]);
```

then I've created a dedicated user for my new db database1

> use database1
>   db.createUser({
>       user: "user1",
>       pwd: "password",
>       roles: ["readWrite", "dbAdmin"]
>   });

after this, I've enabled auth an so I user db.auth to working with my database1 (using "user1").

That's good and it works.

Now, my problem is: I need to create other database and then create a dedicated user for admin this database but, with auth enabled I can't do anything on the new created database database2. If I try, using my mongo_admin superuser to connect to the new database2 and trying to create a dbAdmin for this database using this command:

```
mongo
db.auth("mongo_admin", "password")
use database2
db.createUser({user: "user2, pwd: "password",roles: ["readWrite", "dbAdmin"]});
```

I recive this error:

```
 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on database2 to execute command
```

So, now I know that I can disable auth and work free on every database but, I don't want to do this because database is on production and I prefer to avoid this.

Any suggestion?